# repositories: /WEB-INF/classes/----------> Parent Classloader:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have following jsp file for login

```
<form method="post" name="loginForm" action="/dasauth/accdoLogin">
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AccoLoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.LoginAccolade</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AccoLoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/accdoLogin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

`LoginAccolade` is servlet which in package `servlets` but still throwing

> ClassNotFound exception

please help with this I also tried to add depended project in RunTimeConfiguration of server.

Comment: Try `<form method="post" name="loginForm" action="accdoLogin">`

Comment: thank you very much for your help now class not found gone  but i still cannot jump to the servlet using  : jsp <form method="post" name="loginForm" action="/accdoLogin">                                                                       web.xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AccoLoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.LoginAccolade</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AccoLoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/accdoLogin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> : now its  : description The requested resource (/accdoLogin) is not available. @NaMaN

Comment: Try removing `/` from action it should be `action="accdoLogin"` not `action="/accdoLogin"`